# Ruby Shoes GUI: Continually Updating Paragraphs

Tags: ruby, shoes

The Shoes GUI kit for Ruby seems like a really nice and easy way to add a GUI to my various scripts, but after banging my head against it, I can't seem to make a paragraph be continually updated with a loop.

Here's my minimal code to show what I'm trying to do:

```
Shoes.app do
    stack do
        @exit = button "Exit"
        @log = stack { para "Logging goes here..." }
        @exit.click { exit }

    end

    loop do
        sleep 1
        contents = `ls`
        @log.append { para contents }
    end

end
```

But this just blocks forever and my GUI never shows up until I kill the ruby process, at which time all my info appears.

I've tried putting the "contents" checking loop and append in a separate class, in its own "stack" or "flow" loop, tried passing @log to a separate class's method as per the "Block Redirection" header in the Shoes Rules (http://shoesrb.com/manual/Rules.html), still no joy after trying everything I can think of. Any ideas how I can get this working? I'm thinking I just don't have a complete grasp on how Shoes sets up the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to list all files in a directory and refresh the list every second, then I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Shoes.app do

  stack do
    @btn_exit = button("Exit") {exit}
    @log = para "Logging goes here..."
  end

  every 1 do
    @log.text = Dir.entries('C:/Test').select{|file| file != "."*file.length}.join("\n")
  end

end
```

Comment: Since OP is writingg a shoes application, it would be more logic to use the "animation" method instead of the "every" method

Answer (score 2):

it seems like you need the `every` method (search for it [here](http://shoesrb.com/manual/Element.html)). The every method will call your code every second (or as many second as you pass in).

Should work like this:

```
every do
  # your appending code
end
```

(might need 1 as an argument, not 100% sure atm)