# Refresh ruby stack with Shoes

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

this can be a very simple question but I have been searching for it a long time and haven't found any valid answer yet...

I am try to do a Shoes app with ruby to get a list of names and save it in a file. I would like to show the list that have been introduced already and as a new name enters the list the list which is shown would be updated. Also, I would like to associate  a delete button to each element of the list so the user can remove that name if needed.

After all this, the only thing that I can get is the part in which you add a name and it gets saved into a list but adding this second stack with a list of all names with a delete button... not so lucky. This is how my code looks like, the functions addName and saveFile are not here but they only do some work with the list. Also, some global variables and constat definitions are not shown:

```
 Shoes.app(title: "My Higgs field!",
   width: APPW, height: APPH, resizable: false) {
     stack{

        flow{
            @edit = edit_line 
            @enter = button "Add"
            @enter.click do
                info "Enter to add #{@edit.text}"
                addName(@edit.text)
            end
        }
        @save_file = button "Guardar ficheiro"
        @save_file.click do
            saveFile
        end
     }
     stack do
        # Show a list with all the names inserted
        $names.each do |name|
            flow{
                @line = para name
                info "Putting line #{@line}"
                @delete = button "Apagar"
                @delete.click do
                    deleteName name
                end
            }
        end
    end
 }
```

Any inputs on this is very wellcome!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Shoes GUI: Continually Updating Paragraphs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067381/ruby-shoes-gui-continually-updating-paragraphs)

Comment: @phoet I already saw that post that is not what I was looking for. It redo the list but at the end you end up with the list repeated a lot of times. I have been trying different approaches but anyone did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Linuxios basically what I want is an updated list with all the inputs I have entered and a button to let me delete it but I can't figure out how to update the list everytime a new item is entered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A shoes question so long not answered ! That can't be.
Here a fully working version, i took the liberty to reorganise everything and use my favorite shoes color: green

```
require 'green_shoes'

Shoes.app(title: "My Higgs field!", width: 200, height: 200, resizable: false) do
    @names, @list = [], nil

    def update
        @list.clear()
        @names.each do |name|
            @list.append do
                flow do
                    para link('del'){del(name); update}, ' ', name
                end
            end
      end
    end

    def add name
        @names << name
        @names = @names.uniq.sort
        update
    end

    def del name
        @names.delete(name)
        update
    end

    stack do
        flow do
            @edit = edit_line(width: 110, height: 23)

            keypress do|k| 
                if k == "\n"
                    add(@edit.text)
                end
            end

            button "Add" do
                add(@edit.text)
            end

            button "Save file" do
                File.open("names.txt", "w+") { |file| file.write(@names.join("\n")) }
                alert("names.txt is saved")
            end
    end

        @list = flow do
            @names.each do |p|
              para p, :size => 10
            end
        end
    end
end
```