# How to implement twitter streaming with green_shoes?

Tags: ruby, twitter, shoes

I'm charmed by `green_shoes` and I want to create twitter client with it.
I achieved to log in twitter and to get home_timeline.

I try to implement streaming funciton, as following.

```
require 'green_shoes'
require 'twitter'

CONSUMER_KEY = 'hoge'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'hoge'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'hoge'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'hoge'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |c|
  c.consumer_key        = CONSUMER_KEY
  c.consumer_secret     = CONSUMER_SECRET
  c.access_token        = ACCESS_TOKEN
  c.access_token_secret = ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
end

stream = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new do |c|
  c.consumer_key        = CONSUMER_KEY
  c.consumer_secret     = CONSUMER_SECRET
  c.access_token        = ACCESS_TOKEN
  c.access_token_secret = ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
end

Shoes.app do
  tweets = client.home_timeline
  stack do
    tweets.each do |t|
      para "#{t.user.name}: #{t.text}"
    end
  end

  stream.user do |obj|
    case obj
    when Twitter::Tweet
      stack do
        para "#{obj.user.name}: #{obj.text}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What should I do?

Comment: look at [Ruby Shoes GUI: Continually Updating Paragraphs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18067381)

Comment: @Sathya Twitter Streaming is not polling. So, the solution is not suitable...