# How can I run terminal commands in Shoes capture the return value

Tags: ruby, shoes

When I run this code in Shoes app I have 'true' value only , without other values

```
Shoes.app do
  stack do
    para system('bundle install')
  end
end
```

I'm need to display other values like gems installed or using or 'Could not locate Gemfile' message

Comment: Why not simply assign the return to a variable and then use para to show that directly? `something = \`ls\` ;
para something
`

Comment: Also, don't forget what the different returns are for the `backtick`, `system` and `exec` methods are.  Using `exec` may surprise you unless you are aware of what it is doing.

Comment: when I use `something = `ls` ; para something` nothing return from `bundle install` , the same problem with `system` and `exec` , no more ideas ? , note : system function only return true or false if the command is run or not but I want to show the full return value

Comment: Exactly, You say nothing is returned, but something is always returned.  Can you show your commands in your question and show what the returns are?  Open up IRB and show what you are trying and what isn't working.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18166465/485864) is likely what you want, it is, in my opinion, identical to what you are asking.

Comment: I'm need to run `bundle install` and I need to show the returned value from the command, if the command is false should be print `Could not locate Gemfile` and if is true should print something like

`Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.5.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.2`
.....

but nothing show in app box

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want to save the result from the system call to a variable and present it as an argument to the `para` method.

Something like:

```
result_of_system_call = `bundle install`
```

That may need to be an instance variable, but regardless of scope issues, the code then should be as simple as you have in your question.

```
para result_of_system_call
```

Notice that those are backticks, not apostrophes or single quotes.